# A comment not showing up in my inbox

Tags: bug, comment, notifications, inbox

I can see the comment from 13 hours ago in the Responses tab but not in the Inbox tab, and I don't see the red notification icon on the main page. This is probably related to the fact that the answer the comment belongs to was temporarily deleted.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Can you link the answer which was temporarily deleted?  What you reveal is so tiny to make out.  What answer was temporarily deleted, and to what question. Please link directly.

Comment: You show fourteen unlinkable comments which makes it impossible to discern to what you are referring.

Comment: Please see [How many complex solutions and real solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402579/how-many-complex-solutions-and-real-solutions-does-the-polynomial-system-has).  There was no bug.  There were in fact two deletions of the answer by dxiv, with lots of editing and deletions and new answer.  That is bound to mess up comment notification, when the answerer to whom you comment keeps deleting, and undelting their answer.  No bug.  That's what is expected to happen.

Comment: I disagree, I think what I'm seeing in Responses and in Inbox shouldn't be out of sync. And, unless there is really some fundamental technical difficulty, I should get a notification when there is a comment addressed to me.

Comment: Not when the post is deleted, under which all comments are deleted. And in this case, the answer was deleted twice.

Comment: I've gotten notifications on comments that, once the question or answer is deleted, the inbox empties the notification from my inbox. Dream on for a perfect world.  I think no one should bomb another country when not provoked.  I think that no one on earth should starve, etc.  But wishing doesn't make it so.  Nor does complaining get the job done.

Comment: You say, not when the post is deleted. But then the system could do a refresh on notifications when the post was undeleted. You admit that something got messed up. My opinion is that it wasn't supposed to happen (and that reporting what I think is a bug is useful).

Comment: @amWhy If your view is "the behavior is not a bug", then that qualifies as an answer, and you should post it as an answer so we can see how the community agrees.

Comment: @MikeEarnest no, because meta has become a ranting page which has too many users, who have become hostile to site policy, and reasoned arguments.  I'd rather not be harassed, Mike. Thank you very much.

Comment: A possibly relevant post on [metase]: [Will @reply in deleted answer appear in user's inbox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231202)